# broadcast hash join in spark with very different task execution times

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

In my spark query, I have a non-equi join where I am broadcasting the smaller table, to perform broadcast hash join.

In the Spark UI, in the statistics table there are some tasks, where the execution takes significantly more time than others.
I thought, if I use broadcast hash join, than the partitions can be distributed evenly - because all the workers have access to the broadcasted table, and so the data can be partitioned independenttly from the join keys(?) -  and so each task will have almost the same execution time.

What can be the reasons for the uneven execution time ?

Answer (score 0):

If think that you should check partitioning of your left table. You are broadcasting right table but you still may have unequal partitions on left table for example from other wide transformations